# Haystack-Whoosh Django search engine works locally but not on production

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

Using Whosh 2.7.4 and Django-Haystack version 2.5.dev1.

We have a similar setup as described here:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKSNciGr8kY&index=16&list=PLxxA5z-8B2xk4szCgFmgonNcCboyNneMD
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-n6_m66TmA&index=22&list=PLxxA5z-8B2xk4szCgFmgonNcCboyNneMD

**settings.py**

```
WHOOSH_INDEX = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'whoosh_index/')

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.whoosh_backend.WhooshEngine',
        'PATH': WHOOSH_INDEX,
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    },
}
```

**ajax.js**

```
$(function(){

        $('#search').keyup(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/search/",
                data: { 
                    'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                },
                success: searchSuccess,
                dataType: 'html'
            });

        });

    });

    function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        $('#search-results').html(data);
    }
```

**views.py**

```
def search_titles(request):
    txt = request.POST.get('search_text', '')
    if txt:
        articles = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=txt)
    # if the post request is empty, return nothing
    # this prevents internal server error with jquery
    else:
        articles = []
    return render_to_response('ajax_search.html', {'articles': articles})


def articles(request):
    language = 'en-gb'
    session_language = 'en-gb'

    if 'lang' in request.COOKIES:
        language = request.COOKIES['lang']

    if 'lang' in request.session:
        session_language = request.session['lang']

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['articles'] = Article.objects.all()
    args['language'] = language
    args['session_language'] = session_language

    return render_to_response('index.html', args)
```

We have tried rebuilding and updating index via manage.py, doesn't give any result. We've also made sure that the production and local version of the Django-Haystack and whoosh modules are the same.

Any ideas? Any kind of assistance would be appreciated ! :)

Comment: Define "does not work". Wrong result, no result, error message?